# Javascript JSON.parse with \u0000

Tags: javascript, json

With JSON.parse:

This works:

```
JSON.parse('{\"V\":\"\u008c\"}') // => { V: '' }
```

This doesn't:

```
JSON.parse('{\"V\":\"\u0000\"}') // >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 6
```

What is the concept here?

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information in the [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). For example:

> **2.5.  Strings**
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
>      quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
>      quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
>      quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
>      through U+001F).

Now, related to your problem, you just need to escape the `\` on your unicode character for the parsing to work:

```
JSON.parse('{"V":"\\u0000"}')
```

Result: `{V: "�"}`

And just for you information, no need to escape the `"` inside a single-quoted string in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that you're expressing your JSON as a Javascript string literal. This is valid JSON:

```
{"V":"\u0000"}
```

This however is a Javascript string containing the value `{"V":"<NUL>"}`:

```
'{\"V\":\"\u0000\"}'
```

Javascript was already interpreting the `\u0000` escape sequence and `JSON.parse` was consequently trying to parse a JSON string with a `NUL` byte in it, which is illegal (`NUL` must be escaped).

The actual Javascript string literal representation of the JSON you were attempting is:

```
JSON.parse('{"V":"\\u0000"}')
                  ↑
```